# It's time to make some ads for over on BiologySE!

Tags: discussion

Many (beta) sites use the Community ads feature on related graduated sites to advertise their community.

Biology's thread for this year's ads is over [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/community-promotion-ads-2018). Currently, none of their ads has reached the threshold of 6 votes to be shown. And we're not there!

I suggest we try and think up some ads to see if we can get some people from Biology to over here.

First we need a catchy slogan and some imagery to get an ad together. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

The image: someone (implied biologist) studying a pet.

Slogan: "we are com**pet**itive too.